# Point Formula based on a dynamic amount

Tags: php, formula

I'm trying to create a dynamic point system based off of how much money is available in a bank account. For instance, if someone has 20 points and we have 100 dollars in the bank account, I want the formula to return something along the lines of $1.

**I don't care too much about the ratio at this point - more about the formula to get there.**

So far, I've come up with a handful of different formulas,

```
$val = (1 / $this->bank) * $amt; //goes the wrong way
$val = ($amt / $this->bank) * 5000; //isn't a good ratio
```

Assume val is the amount you can get with all the points, bank is how much is in the bank, and $amt is the amount of points the user has.

A gentle nudge in the right direction would be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: So you're saying you don't care what the calculation does, as long as a single test case is satisfied? `$bank * ($points / 2000)` satisfies your test case, giving `1` for `$bank = 100` and `$points = 20`.

Comment: That was the ticket, I was dividing the bank - not the points. That's exactly that I needed, my formula's weren't working for the entire scope. Would you mind making that an answer for some rep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bank * ($points / 2000)
```

This satisfies your test case, giving `1` for `$bank = 100` and `$points = 20`.

Answer (score 1):

Saying $percentage is the percentage you want between your points and the bank account amount to have 1$ reward, you will have:

```
$percentage = 20;
$val = $amt * $this->bank / ($percentage * 100);
```